# Не работает Post запрос Spring boot и Thymealeaf

Tags: post, spring-boot, request, thymeleaf

Доброе утро.
Делала все по инструкции. В других проектах все работает, а в этом не удается найти ошибку. На сервер запрос даже не уходит, чтобы вывести сообщение о какой-то проблеме. А в браузере "Whitelabel Error Page", хотя нажав на F12 видно, что он пытается по правильной ссылке стучаться. Помогите, пожалуйста

**Контроллеры**

```
@GetMapping("/report/search")
public String PageTest(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("infoParam", new PaymentOrderArchiveParam());
    return "searchDocument";
}

@PostMapping("/report/searchDoc")
@ResponseBody
public String searchDoc(@ModelAttribute PaymentOrderArchiveParam infoParam, ModelMap model){
    System.out.println(infoParam);
    return "main";
}
```

**Форма отправки запроса**

```
       <form action="#" th:action="@{/report/searchDoc}" th:object="${infoParam}" method="post">
        <div class="row border border-secondary">
            <div class="col-3 p-2">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="spanNumberDoc">№ документа</span>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{documentnumber}" name="documentnumber" class="form-control" aria-describedby="spanNumberDoc">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3  p-2">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="spanNumberDateS">Дата документа с</span>
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{documentdateStart}"  name="documentdateStart"  class="form-control" aria-describedby="spanNumberDateS">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3  p-2">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="spanNumberDateE">по</span>
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{documentdateEnd}" name="documentdateEnd"  class="form-control" aria-describedby="spanNumberDateE">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3  p-2">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="spanSum">Сумма</span>
                    <input type="number" step="any" th:field="*{amount}"  name="amount" class="form-control" aria-describedby="spanSum">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--           Данные о сторонах договора -->
        <div class="row border border-secondary">
                <div class="col-6 border border-secondary">
                    <span> Плательщик </span>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanPayerINN">ИНН</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{payerinn}" name="payerinn"   aria-describedby="spanPayerINN">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanPayerName">Наименование</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{payername}" name="payername"  aria-describedby="spanPayerName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanPayerAccount">Счет</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{payeraccount}" name="payeraccount"  aria-describedby="spanPayerAccount">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 border border-secondary">
                    <span> Получатель </span>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanReceiverINN">ИНН</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  th:field="*{receiverinn}" name="receiverinn"  aria-describedby="spanReceiverINN">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanReceiverName">Наименование</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{receivername}" name="receivername" aria-describedby="spanReceiverName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="spanReceiverAccount">Счет</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{payeraccount}"  name="payeraccount"  aria-describedby="spanReceiverAccount">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!--           Назначение платежа  -->
        <div class="row border border-secondary">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3  p-2">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="spanGround">Назначение платежа</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " th:field="*{ground}"  name="ground" aria-describedby="spanGround">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-dark" value="Найти" />
        </div>
        </form>
```

На всякий случай класс, отправляемый в запросе

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PaymentOrderArchiveParam {
private String receiverinn;
private String receiveraccount;
private String receivername;

private String payerinn;
private String payeraccount;
private String payername;

private String ground;
private String documentnumber;
private Double amount;

private Date documentdateStart;
private Date documentdateEnd;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

А ларчик просто открывался. Оказалась подобная форма не понимает даты. Сделала из дат строки - все пошло хорошо